# Help with complex MVVM (multiple views)

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I need help creating view models for the following scenario:

1. Deep, hierarchical data
2. Multiple views for the same set of data
3. Each view is a single, dynamically-changing view, based on the active selection
4. Depending on the value of a property, display different types of tabs in a tab control

[image]

My questions:

**Should I create a view-model representation for each view (VM1, VM2, etc)?**

```
1. Yes:
    a. Should I model the entire hierarchical relationship? (ie, SubVM1, HouseVM1, RoomVM1)
    b. How do I keep all hierarchies in sync? (e.g, adding/removing nodes)

2. No:
    a. Do I use a huge, single view model that caters for all views?
```

Here's an example of a single view

Figure 1: Multiple views updated based on active room. Notice Tab control

[image]

Figure 2: Different active room. Multiple views updated. Tab control items changed based on object's property.

[image]

Figure 3: Different selection type. Entire view changes

[image]

Comment: btw what is a muli view? typo?

Comment: "Muli view" was a typo. I meant different views for the same model/view model. My question was, should I remodel/wrap the entire model hierarchy for each view, so each view model only contains what the individual view needs? Or should I create a single view model hierarchy that contains properties from all views? Since I posted this question, I was (un)fortunate enough to find out the pros/cons of the two, the hard way. Will update this thread in the future with a full diagnosis of my experience, once things aren't as hectic.

Comment: Remember a design rule is to show general things first then go deep into details. it will leave you with a light view and if the user go deeper then new views will appear. so use small views with their viewmodel apart. check this article [design user interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728824%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @jsjslim I shuddered when I read "keep all hierarchies in sync".  I suspect you went with the multi-view, and I suspect you regretted it (but I've been wrong before).  For the sake of other readers who may have the same question, can you at least give us a quick(ish) answer?

Comment: @guy-schalnat The multi-view was a requirement. My problem was trying to figure out how to build the view models. The project is still ongoing, and I can't find the time to write-up a full analysis. But in summary: I should have ignored the model structure, and focused on the views. The complexity that I encountered was self-imposed: I wanted to use WPF's data binding so badly, I got fixated. What I did in the end was good, old "copy/paste/refactor". The final design that emerged was lightweight (little repetition), and more importantly, worked. Will write up a full analysis in the future.

Comment: @jsjslim - Thanks for the reply.  Even that little bit is dripping with wisdom and will be very helpful for other readers in situations similar to yours.  I'll look forward to the full answer sometime in the future (you can answer your own question and accept it, please, so it gets out of the unanswered questions list).

Comment: Create multiple view model and use composition and maintain parent child relationship, use Lazy Loading, use different Model/ Interfaces for different view

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To answer the question, Yes, each view should have its own View Model.
But there is no need to model the entire hierarchy. Only what the view needs.

The problem I had with most online resources regarding MVVM:

In most examples, the View is almost 1-to-1 mapping of the Model.
But in my scenario, where there are different views for different facets of the same Model, I find myself stuck between two choices:

One monolithic view model that is used by all other view models

[image]

Or one view model for each view

[image]

But both are not ideal.

The Model-oriented View Model (MVM), while low in code duplication, is a nightmare to maintain

The View-oriented View Model (VVM) produces highly-specialised classes for each view, but contains duplicates.

In the end, I decided that having one VM per View is easier to maintain and code for, so I went with the VVM approach.

Once the code is working, I began refactoring all common properties and operations into its current, final form:

[image]

In this final form, the common view model class is composed into each VVM.

Of course, I still have to decide what is considered common/specialised. And when a view is added/merged/deleted, this balance changes.

But the nice thing about this is, I am now able to push up/down members from common to VVM and vice versa easily.

And a quick note regarding keeping the objects in-sync:

Having a Common View Model takes care of most of this. Each VVM can simply have a reference to the same Common View Model.

I also tend to start with simple callback methods, and evolving to event/observer if the need for multiple listeners arise.

And for really complex events (ie, unexpected cascading updates), I would switch over to using a Mediator.

I do not shy away from code where a child has a back reference to its parent. Anything to get the code working.

And if the opportunity to refactor arise, I would take it.

The lessons I learnt:

1. Ugly/Working code > Beautiful/Non-working code
2. It is easier to merge multiple small classes, than it is to break up a huge class

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice. This is one of the clearest explanations of the options I've seen.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your mockups, I would definitely recommend creating hierarchy of ViewModels and lots of small Views. And you will most probably have to model quite a bit of the original hierarchy.

To keep things in sync between ViewModels, use either events, or have properties to each other between ViewModels. Sync between Views and ViewModels should be standard notifying properties.